# Is there another word for something that is conjured besides a conjuration?

Tags: single-word-requests

I have this feeling there is a word for the product of a conjuring related to the word *conjure*. Obviously it’s not *conjugations*, but that’s what my brain wants to say. It may not be strictly related to the word *conjure* itself either, but simply directly related to ***a*** conjuring.

Sentence:

> The ______ of last night’s conjuring still danced around the house.

Comment: You may be thinking of *materialization*. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Materialization https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Materialization_(paranormal)

Comment: What dose "conjure* mean?  [One definition](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/conjure) is *to summon a devil or spirit by invocation or incantation*.  [Oxford](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/conjure) gives several possibilities.

Comment: Please explain how “conjugations” has a place here; how is that related to “conjurations”?

Isn’t the obvious filler for the gap in your “The … of last night’s conjuring…” simply “…result”?

How would that let you down?

Comment: There is the word "familiar" which is a spirit or demon, usually summoned, often by witches and sorcerers. You often hear of witches' cat familiars, otherwise known as spirit guides. You'll find the term in dictionaries, and here's the Wikipedia article for it https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Familiar_spirit

Answer (score 1):

Would you be amenable to a slight change in your example sentence?

> Those **summoned** by last night’s conjuring still danced around the house.

From Merriam-Webster's [*summon*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/summon):

> **1** : to issue a call to convene : CONVOKE
>   **3** : to call upon for specified action
>   **4** : to bid to come : send for • *summon* a physician
>   **5** : to call forth : EVOKE —often used with *up*

In the example sentence, it's being used a verb rather than a noun. However, you can also use **the summoned** as a noun with a different construction:

> The morning after the conjuring, **the summoned** still danced around the house.